# Why some jQuery programmers use jQuery functions like $.get, $.getJSON and $.when instead $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, getjson

My Question is that if you have everything in your jQuery `$.ajax` function why use `$.get()`, `$.getJSON()`, `$.when()` and others that I have seen, is not better to use just ajax cause I can tell you that you almost use the same number of characters writting those functions then with traditional `$.ajax`.

What is the diference in addition to just simplify those function names?

Comment: `$.when` has nothing to do with those other functions. As for the others: They just set some parameters for you, so they simply exists for convenience...

Comment: @Felix Kling: `$.when()` was added as a "pick the wrong item from the list" competition. And you won it ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a short-hand for commonly used behaviour. I use those methods for two reasons:

1. It's less typing, so less room for minor "brain-fart" errors.
2. There are much fewer arguments, so you don't have to memorize all the things you need to pass to `$.ajax` or spend time going back to the docs.

Functionality-wise there isn't a difference, those methods just provide some defaults for you.

Comment: Did not know that some of that functions provide defaults so that they can be used only for that purpose, nice!!

Comment: @Ivan: It's mentioned in the respective documentation ;) http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/